# Is there a WordReader similar to a PdfReader?

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, ms-word, document

I have pdf files that get loaded with prefilled information, but would like to have similar functionality for a word document. How do I go about this?  To access the pdf files I am using the following code:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(Server.MapPath("~/Content/path.pdf"));
MemoryStream newPdf = ModifyPdf(reader);
return File(newPdf.GetBuffer().ToArray(), "application/pdf", Server.UrlEncode("name.pdf"));
```

ModifyPdf sets up the PdfStamper and AcroFields etc.

My current document code gets a file from my desktop, make edits then save as a new file to my desktop. How do I have the file get pulled from my Content folder in the project similar to the pdf, make edits, then get "dowloaded" for viewing similar to the pdf?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if there is any WordReader but you can use 'Open XML SDK 2.0 for Microsoft Office' to get your job done and can be downloaded from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124). There are planty of examples regarding working (opening, changing, saving etc) with word document. If you need any help regarding Open XML, I also can provide you the code samples.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can also use COM interop to automate much of Words (and other Office applications) functionality.

Comment: Yes COM Interop can be used but it is not that good as Open XML is. First of all the performace issue, Interop processing is slower as compare to the Open XML and also Interop has dependencies on Word and Excel etc. so licensing can be another issue. There are very good comparasons available online. Some of the OpenXML advantages can be found from Eric White's blog at the following link http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2009/02/13/seven-key-benefits-of-open-xml.aspx

Comment: As well as requiring that Word is present for COM interop, you also need to code for Late Binding which then means you won't have all the syntax helpers / autocomplete in the IDE or you get bound to a specific Word version.